# Is there a backup of Ray Aldridge's site with his stories?

Tags: authors

There used to be a website with stories by [Ray Aldridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_Aldridge), but I lost the bookmark, so I can't find it on Wayback Machine (not that I'm sure it is there). The website had also illustrations that looked like stained glass. Another part of the site was styled like some cybercorp website hijacked by hackers, or something like that. It was a lovely and haunting piece of art. His personal sites goodpots.com and another about boat building are also defunct. In general, if anyone has any updates on him, I'd be grateful. The wiki does not have the date of death, fwiw.

Comment: Was it an official website where he was publishing his stories or just a random website where someone was posting them?

Comment: I don't see any evidence he's not still alive, FWIW.

Comment: @Clockwork - As far as I can remember it was at least endorsed by the author, if not commissioned or created by him. I don't really remember why I have this impression; I have last accessed it more than 10 years ago. Also, it was not a website made for publishing his stories. More of a one off art project, like a glimpse into an alternate universe.

Comment: @DavidW, I certainly hope so. His life and works have always fascinated me, but I can understand that he does not want to be contacted. Just hoping to learn the guy is OK and enjoying whatever he is into now.

Comment: I highly doubt these are what you're looking for, but still posting just in case: https://web.archive.org/web/20030526153034/http://goodpots.com/ and https://web.archive.org/web/20030602174454/http://goodpots.com/light/strmwal1.html

Comment: @Clockwork, Thank you so much! In the first link you posted, in the sidebar, there is link to "Science fiction stained glass" - this is the very site I was looking for! I hope you enjoy it as much as I did (and will do, thank to you). Here is the direct link: https://web.archive.org/web/20030602174454/http://goodpots.com/light/strmwal1.html

Comment: @Clockwork: sorry, I'm new and I just realized I should have let you post the answer and upvote it. Can I delete my answer so you can post yours? Again, sorry for the breach of etiquette.

Comment: Nah, I'm fine with it. Glad it turned out to be the right one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [a comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/260827/is-there-a-backup-of-ray-aldridges-site-with-his-stories/260909#comment718659_260827) by user Clockwork, here is [the link](https://web.archive.org/web/20030602174454/http://goodpots.com/light/strmwal1.html) to the archived version of the website.

Comment: Don't forget to self-accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - thanks, done! I'm new, so I appreciate the hints.